# Remove/Delete current line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, context-menu

Specifically I want to make a context menu option that (on rightclick) removes/deletes the current line. The catch is the line should be deleted even if it´s not selected. Meaning I don't have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> & <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> or mouse to select the line before deleting. The only required thing would be just a click on the line making it selected.
I also need a string for `shortcuts.xml` file so this would show up under the Run menu. I can edit `contextmenu.xml` myself because that's the easy part.

Is it possible?
I looked at various N++ commands and there were some Scintilla commands that looked like what I needed but I had no luck putting them into `shortcuts.xml` so they would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I also need a string for shortcuts.xml file so this would show up under the Run menu.

This part cannot be done. The Run menu only contains external commands.

> Specifically i want to make a context menu option that (on rightclick) removes/deletes the current line.

This can be easily done using a macro:

1. Click `Macro -> Start Recording`.
2. Mimic deleting the current line by pressing the following keys:

   <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>

   (The second <kbd>Home</kbd> is to remove possible indentation.)
3. Click `Macro -> Stop Recording`.
4. Click `Macro -> Save Current Recorded Macro...`.
5. Choose a `macro_name` (mandatory) and a key combination (optional).
6. Click `OK`.
7. Edit the `contextMenu.xml` and add the following line:

   ```
   <Item MenuEntryName="Macro" MenuItemName="macro_name"/>
   ```
8. Restart Notepad++.

Comment: Here's an upvote++ for your great Notepad++ answers. :)

Comment: Dig in deep of N++..... ++1 :)

Comment: if you have time check out my other topic. It's very similar: http://superuser.com/questions/424562/notepad-run-current-line-in-command-prompt