# Add code snippets to Notepad++ context menu

Tags: notepad++, context-menu, code, snippets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove/Delete current line in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/424559/remove-delete-current-line-in-notepad)

Possible?
Basicly i want to add some of my most used commands by modifying shortcuts.xml and contextmenu.xml